# FreeBSD 9.0 supports only IPv6. What this practically means?

Tags: freebsd, ipv6

I have very scarce knowledge of IPv6 but I'm considering installing FreeBSD on an RDC device which acts as a server to my home network running services.
The last release states that one of the changes is IPv6 support **only**. I don't quite understand how will this affect my network, other devices etc. Should my ISP support IPv6 in some way in order for me to use FreeBSD etc? I'm also using services like dyndns to connect back to my home server via internet. Will that address respond to IPv6 addresses only?

Comment: Wait, what? I just installed FreeBSD 9.0 yesterday and I configured ipv4 on the machine. I don't know where you read that, but that is definitely *wrong*.

Comment: Yeah I got victim of FUD. There other people who don't quite understand the things I've asked and replicate false deductions. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not quite! It still supports both IPv4 and IPv6, but it is now possible, if desired, to build an IPv6-only kernel.

You can still still install FreeBSD with just an IPv4 address. If you obtain an IPv6 allocation you can configure this too.

Comment: See also: http://www.freebsd.org/ipv6/ipv6only.html

Answer (score 2):

I think FreeBSD still has a dual-stack, so you shouldn't have any problems. And IPv6 is mostly backwards compatible, even if it were just IPv6 supported instead of IPv4.

From their site, it sounds like there's an IPv6-only kernel available...implying it still supports IP4.

http://www.freebsd.org/ipv6/ipv6only.html